# Recorded Video from iPhone is playing in landscape mode in windows OS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I recorded a video in my iPhone app and then saved it. When I play this video in MAC OS it is playing in portrait mode. But when same video is played in windows OS its orientations changes to landscape mode.

Why so? How to resolve it?